# MySQL replication issues with recording client history

Tags: php, mysql, database-replication

I have two LAMP servers, a master and a slave.

The master's web root gets mirrored onto the slave using RSync,
and the databases get replicated onto the slave using MySQL replication.

The master is in on our office LAN. We use it to capture data and generate reports.
The slave is what clients access to use our website.

All client activity needs to get saved to the database. The obvious problem is that if the slave is allowed to write to the database, it goes out of sync with the master.

If the slave becomes unavailable, client traffic is redirected to temporarily use the master (DNS failover)

Do you have any ideas for recording client activity to the database without breaking the master/slave sync.

So far the best I can come up with is to not replicate the database containing client usage history. But some say it is risky not to replicate all tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about .... switching the roles, your old master is the slave and your old slave becomes the master.
therefore, you shouldnt run into the sync-problems you mentioned.

as with your "ps", you could use an alternate database for that. all tables that need to be sync-ed could be in one database, all non-synced in the other db.

Comment: The idea of having an additional database for non-replicated tables seems like the way to go for now.